# How to customize naming convention for c# project

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have a project where I have to follow a specific type of naming convention for private and public members.

I was using VS static code analysis and was very happy with it.

My project has many class library projects and Now I have to do the following :
Run a scan on all libraries and see if specific naming convention is followed or not.

i.e. 
I have declared :
`int _itemID;`

it should be reported invalid naming convention 
correct should be "
`int iItemId;`
or 
`int intItemId;`

How can make a tool to identify such declarations?

Comment: ...and adjust your styles. Hungarian notation has not been anyones standard in years, especially given that it takes 1ms (or less) for modern IDEs to tell you what type a variable is by hovering over it .. if you need inspiration, just stick to the style that MSDN uses.

Comment: This isn't even Hungarian. Hungarian prefixes the variable's name with *semantic* information about it's name. All that you've done here is repeat the type name. That's completely pointless. Notice how stupid `int intItemId` looks? It's like you've got a stutter.

Comment: I understand this is not even Hungarian. But i need it as I have asked in the question.I think I have to create some kinda utility tool to do this, But I do not know where to start or even if there is a need to create one. thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)?

> ReSharper can reformat an arbitrary selected block of code, all code in the current file, all files in a directory, or even in the entire project or solution, according to your Code Style preferences. ReSharper provides distinct formatting options for C#, VB.NET, JavaScript, CSS and XML code. Reformatting affects braces layout, blank lines, line wrapping and line breaks, spaces in various contexts, indentation, aligning multiple constructs, and a lot more options that you can fine-tune in the ReSharper Options dialog box.